# How can I get an instance in StructureMap Registy constructor?

Tags: .net, structuremap

How can I get an instance of some type (registered in a different Registry) inside StructureMap Registy constructor? I want to use such a code:

```
    public RepositoriesRegistry()
    {
        IApplicationSettings lApplicationSettings =
            ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IApplicationSettings>();
        Debug.Assert(lApplicationSettings != null);

        const string cSupportedDevicesConnectionString =
            "metadata=res://*/Models.SupportedDevices.Database.SupportedDevicesModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SupportedDevices.Database.SupportedDevicesModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SupportedDevices.Database.SupportedDevicesModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"{0}\"";
        string lSupportedDevicesConnectionString =
            string.Format(cSupportedDevicesConnectionString, lDatabaseConnectionString);
        SupportedDevicesEntities lSupportedDevicesEntities =
            new SupportedDevicesEntities(lSupportedDevicesConnectionString);
        ForRequestedType<SupportedDevicesEntities>().TheDefault.IsThis(
            lSupportedDevicesEntities);
        ForRequestedType<ISupportedDevicesRepository>().TheDefault.IsThis(
            new SupportedDevicesRepository(lSupportedDevicesEntities));

    }
```

IApplicationSettings is an interface to application settings. The concrete type implementing this interface (currently ConfigFileApplicationSettings class) is registered in another registry like this:

```
    public ApplicationServicesRegistry()
    {
        ForRequestedType<IApplicationSettings>().TheDefault.IsThis(
            new ConfigFileApplicationSettings());
    }
```

And both registries are registered in the Bootstrapper:

```
        #region IBootstrapper Members

    public void BootstrapStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(InitalizeStructureMapContainer);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private properties

    private static bool HasStarted { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private void InitalizeStructureMapContainer(IInitializationExpression x)
    {
        x.IgnoreStructureMapConfig = true;
        x.AddRegistry<ViewModelRegistry>();
        x.AddRegistry<ApplicationServicesRegistry>();
        x.AddRegistry<RepositoriesRegistry>();
        x.AddRegistry<DataOperationsRegistry>();
    }

    #endregion
```

When I try to get an instance of IApplicationRegisty in registry constructor I've got an error (of course). I don't completly understand how to use StructureMap the right way. May be I should do the thing some different way. But anyway can I get an instance of some type early registered in an Registry constructor?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this same problem today. The answer from Jeremy Miller (no relation :) ) is that StructureMap is not setup to create instances at configuration time.

The workaround he recommended and that I used was to create a container just for the settings. Here is my solution.

```
public class SettingsRegistry : Registry
{
    public SettingsRegistry()
    {
        ForRequestedType<ISettingsProvider>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<AppSettingsProvider>();

        Scan(s =>
        {
            s.TheCallingAssembly();
            s.With<SettingsScanner>();
        });
    }
}

public class RegistryNeedingSettings : Registry
{
    public RegistryNeedingSettings()
    {
        var settingsContainer = new Container(new SettingsRegistry());
        var coreSettings = settingsContainer.GetInstance<CoreSettings>();

        //configuration needing access to the settings.
    }
}
```

I moved everything settings into its own registry and made sure the settings registry gets configured before the dependent registry.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's been 9years, I'd like to know how do you do it today?